# Stack write order and code execution order

Tags: assembly, stack, dos, x86-16, real-mode

I was reading a famous book from the 1980s by Peter Norton and John Sohna, who state, at least in the Italian version, that:

given an assembly code without the definition of the space reserved for STACK (therefore without the .STACK directive in the code), by assembling it, linking it and then observing its register states with DEBUG (directly from the .EXE file), we have the following:

```
A> DEBUG TEST_SEG.EXE
-R
AX = OOOO BX = OOOO CX = 0004 DX = OOOO SP = OOOO BP = OOOO SI = OOOO DI = OOOO
DS = 3985 ES = 3985 SS = 3995 CS = 3995 IP = OOOO NV UP EI PL NZ NA PO NC
3995:0000 B44C           MOV       AH, 4C
-
```

the book also says:
The stack is now at 3995: 0, which is the start of the program (CS: O). This is absolutely not good. The stack must never be near the program code. Also, since the stack pointer is in SS: O, it has no room to grow (as the stack grows down). For these reasons, you must define a stack segment for .EXE programs.

Now, I did some tests, and I understand that the stack grows downwards (ie for example, from 0000h, FFFEh, FFFCh, FFFA, etc.), then from the highest address to the bottom (lowest address). The Instruction Pointer (IP) instead grows from the lowest address (in the example from 0000h), towards higher addresses.
By inserting data into the stack and adding code into the program, these two will not meet (at least for a while) since there is a 64K memory margin.

So, this .EXE program behaves more or less as if it were a .COM in my opinion.

Is what is written in the book correct (in this case I am missing something), or what I experienced actually corresponds to the truth and therefore in the book (at least in the Italian version) there is an error?

Comment: You are right: the stack is just below the code segment. I don't remember how DOS initialized the EXEs though, the stack may be close to the PSP or in an "unreserved" area. As a side note, beware of very old books and their translations.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Unlike .COM files (which don't have a header), the initial position of the stack pointer is specified in the header of each .EXE file.

Comment: The stack grows to lower addresses, and, shrinks to higher addresses, dynamically as the program runs.  However, the code only "grows" at compile/link time rather than at runtime: once running, the program code is fixed in size.  The IP register tracks what instruction the processor is on, dynamically.  Sometimes we call the current end of the code the location counter, to differentiate the compile time concept of growing code from the dynamic concept of the instruction pointer.

Comment: I don't remember the details of DOS memory allocation, but can we be sure that 3995:FFFE is actually available for use by this program, and not allocated to another one?  If not, you may have just overwritten someone else's code or data.

Comment: @NateEldredge Fields in the EXE header could guarantee that the space was allocated to the program.  If the linker allocated space for the stack as rcgldr's answer suggests then the fields would presumably set to allocate this space.  However, I'm not sure if this actually what MS-DOS linkers actually did.

Comment: @RossRidge - defaulting stack space is what 16 bit Microsoft (MSDOS) linkers do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Peter Norton's book is correct. You should define a stack using the `.STACK` directive when creating a DOS EXE (MZ) program to avoid undefined behaviour. Alternatively you can create a segment named `STACK` with a class called `STACK` using the `SEGMENT`/`ENDS` directives with an appropriate `BYTE ### DUP(?)` statement where `###` is the stack size in bytes.

---

I have the English version of the book ([3rd Edition](https://www.amazon.ca/Assembly-Language-Pc-Book-Disk/dp/1566860164/ref=sr_1_3)) that seems to be the equivalent of what you are quoting:

> DOS always sets the stack pointer to the very end of the segment when
> it loads a COM file into memory. For this reason, you do not need to
> declare a stack segment (with .STACK) for COM files. What would happen
> if you removed the .STACK directive from TEST_SEG.ASM?
>
> ```
> C>DEBUG TEST_SEG.EXE
> R
> AX=0000 BX=0000 CX=0004 DX=0000 SP=0000 BP=0000 SI=0000 DI=0000
> DS=3985 ES=3985 SS=3995 CS=3995 IP=0000 NV UP EI PL NZ NA PO NC 
> 3090:0000 B44C MOV AH,4C
> ```
>
> The stack is now at 3995:0, which is the start of your program (CS:0).
> This is very bad news. You do not want the stack anywhere near your
> program's code. Since the stack pointer is at SS:0, it has no room to
> grow (since the stack grows down in memory). For these reasons, you
> must declare a stack segment for EXE programs.

The DOS EXE (MZ) program format includes a [header](https://bytepointer.com/resources/dos_programmers_ref_exe_format.htm) that includes fields specifying the starting stack value *SS:SP*. The value of *SP* will be the size of the stack requested with the `.STACK` directive. If the `.STACK` directive doesn't have a value specified it is generally defaulted to 1024 bytes (0x400 bytes) for most MASM and compatible assemblers.

When you specify the `.STACK` directive the linker will be directed to generate an *SS:SP* value that doesn't conflict with other segments in the EXE program.

The DOS EXE file format allows the segments to be relocated when the program is loaded in memory. The value of *SS* written into the header for the stack pointer is a value relative to a *CS* that is initially set to zero. When the DOS loader reads the EXE program into memory it will perform fixups to the program including *SS:SP* value in the header. If for example you have a DOS EXE program where *SS:SP* in the header is set by the linker to 0x0002:0x0400 and the DOS loader loads your program to segment 0x3995 then the stack (*SS:SP*) will be set to 0x3995+2:0x0400 = 0x3997:0x0400.

The linker specifies how much memory a program needs and writes the appropriate information into the header. When the DOS loader reads the header it checks to determine if there is enough memory, and this includes the stack segment.

---

### What Happens when you Don't Use .STACK in an EXE Program?

When `.STACK` isn't specified in your assembly code the value written by the linker to the *SS:SP* fields in the header will be set to 0x0000:0x0000. This means that when the DOS loader relocates the segment and sets up *SS:SP* the effective memory location will be the same as *CS:0x0000*. This means if your *CS* segment has 65536 bytes of code in it (enough to fill the entire segment) your stack will grow down over top of it. As an example if you push a 16 bit value on the stack the stack pointer will have 2 subtracted from it and the value written to that location. That would be *CS:0xFFFE*. As well, there isn't actually guarantee that *CS:0xFFFE* and *CS:0xFFFF* are even available memory to your program! When you don't specify a stack it doesn't contribute to the size of the program written by the linker to the header fields. When the DOS loader reads it into memory it will have no idea if there is enough memory for your stack or not.

This is why most linkers will warn you that you are generating an EXE without a defined stack. If you don't specify a stack, when loaded into memory it will probably work just fine if the location of the stack is somewhere within your program space or is in an unused area of space not being used by DOS or another application. You shouldn't rely on getting lucky.

What Peter Norton is suggesting is that you should always use a `.STACK` directive or define your own stack segment explicitly using the `SEGMENT`/`ENDS` directive with an appropriate number of bytes allocated to it. This is so your program will be loaded by DOS as you expect and run as you expect.

---

### Converting EXE to COM Programs with Early Development Tools

One reason that you may wish to produce an EXE without a stack is when you are using old versions of MASM and a linker that couldn't generate a COM program directly. In early versions of MASM there was no `TINY` model. To generate a COM program you created a `SMALL` model program that had no stack specified and no segment relocations and then you'd use the linker to generate the EXE program. If the EXE program meets the requirements of a COM program it can be converted from an EXE. [`EXE2BIN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exe2bin) was a program that could attempt to do such a conversion. A DOS COM program when initially loaded has the stack (*SS:SP*) set to the last paragraph aligned memory address available at the end of the code segment. It then pushes 0x0000 onto the stack. This was to retain compatibility with CP/M. The DOS loader pushes the value 0x0000 on the stack so that you can do a `RET` to terminate the program. The address *CS:0x0000* is in the DOS PSP and contain an [`Int 0x20`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2471.htm) instruction to terminate the program.

When loading a DOS COM program: If the DOS loader finds that there is a full 64KiB of memory available the value of *SS* will be set to the segment the DOS [Program Segment Prefix (PSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix) is in and it will set SP to 0x0000 and push 0x0000 on the stack. This is why you will often see an initial *SS:SP* in a DOS COM program start at *CS:0xFFFE* when viewed in the debugger.

I do not know why in the Peter Norton book the value for SP is 0xFFEE (`SP=FFEE`) in the debug trace output. It looks unusual but is still valid. It may be the version of DOS he was using; the amount of memory available; or his debugger placed something else in the top 16 bytes above the 0x0000 return address.

Answer (score 4):

> The stack is now at 3995:0, which is the start of the program (CS:0). This is absolutely not good. The stack must never be near the program code.

As long as the stack is before the code, this is absolutely not a problem:

The stack grows downwards and the stack pointer is decremented first. (There are CPU types where `push` first writes the value and then changes the SP; on such CPUs it would be a problem.)

So it would not be a problem if both the initial SS:SP and the initial CS:IP are 0:7C00. (This is a typical combination for boot sectors.)

> Also, since the stack pointer is in SS:0, it has no room to grow.

This is correct:

In some operating modes, x86 CPUs do not allow `push` (or `call` ...) if SP is 0.

Instead of wrapping to 0xFFFE, the program may simply crash.

And of course you have another problem: If the program is longer than 64K and CS=SS, a `push` operation will overwrite program code if SP wraps from SS:0 to SS:0xFFFE.

Comment: The question mentions 16 bit, which I assume means real mode (as opposed to 286 protected mode, and even then, sp == 0 gets decremented to fffe before a push). If the program is longer than 64K, then multiple segments are needed, and the linker will still provide a default stack if the code or command line don't specify a stack size.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is 16 bit real mode code, if ss:sp = 3395:0000, it is actually at the end of the code segment, since sp is decremented to fffe before doing any push.

Since the source code or command line didn't specify a stack size, the linker defaulted to putting the stack at the end of the code segment.